I am able to access Registry base key object even after I disposed the object. Is this expected?
I'm trying to fetch some values from registry key. After getting the value, I observed that the subkey was getting disposed after calling key.Close(). But the base key was still available after calling Close() method on that object and I was able to open new sub keys with that closed base key. According to the documents calling close should destroy the object. Is this an expected behavior?
Below is the code I tried.
 var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default);
 var key =  baseKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon", true);
 baseKey.Close();
 var testValue = key.GetValue("TestNameInWinlogon");
 key.Close();
 key = baseKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Windows", true);
 testValue = key.GetValue("TestNameInWindows");
 key.Close();

I tried it with C# and .NET Framework 4.8

Behavior is similar if Dispose() is used instead of Close().
RegistryKey Documentation.

It is specific to a "base key", they don't need an OS handle to get their job done.  Or to put it another way, the OS always keeps the root of a registry hive accessible.

In order for a class to throw an exception if you try to use it after it's been disposed, someone has to write the code to check whether it's been disposed and throw an exception if so: it doesn't happen automatically. This might just be an oversight on the part of the author. It would be best to keep to the contract and and not use an object after it's been disposed. Note that Close != Dispose: it might be expected that you can use an object after closing it (e.g. re-opening it)

Looking at the source code, you can see:

OpenBaseKey passes systemkey: true to the RegistryKey constructor;
Close simply calls Dispose; and
the Dispose method does nothing if the key is marked as a "system key".

Therefore: yes, it is expected behaviour that calling Close or Dispose on a base key will not destroy the object, or prevent you from using it for further calls.
NB: The same is true in the .NET Framework source as well.

Note however that this doesn't match what the documentation says so it would be "poor form" to rely on this. If you're planning to reuse the object later, don't call Dispose on it and the whole premise of the question disappears.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever It is documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.close?view=net-8.0#remarks

This is explicitly documented, but not on the Dispose method, it's in the Close method docs

Remarks
Calling this method on system keys will have no effect, because system keys are never closed.

Close calls Dispose, so the effect is the same.

But can you find a definition of "system key" other than perusing source code? :-)
